# Bitcoin wallet address on Dream Market

Tags: help, onion-routing

I cannot get my bitcoin wallet full on Dream Market because the Bitcoin address is only valid for 10 days but then they don't give you a new one or the tip to get a new BTC address.Can you help me solve the problem?

Thank you and Kind Regards

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin addresses are valid indefinitely

Answer (score 0):

I found this blog post which clearly states that the Dream Market has been closed for quite a while now.

https://deeponionweb.com/2019/05/10/dream-market-admin-update/

Suggest you try any of the other darknets markets such as Agara Market, Empire Market or Nightmare Market they are all equally as good. You can try a Tor directory such as

https://onion.live

to help you in your search hope that helped if not just reply and I will do my best on advising you.